# How can I remove code duplication caused by an union member and its implicitly deleted member functions?

Tags: c++

I have a template class `C<T>` that should be instantiable with `C<U>` when `T` can be constructed with `U`. As the code below shows, I have some duplicate code; can I defer the call to the template copy-ctor?

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() {}

    template <typename U>
    C( C<U> const& other ) { /* ... duplicate code ... */ }

    // required, since union automatically declares this overload as deleted
    C( C const& other ) { /* ... duplicate code ... */ }

private:
    union
    {
        T t;
    };
};
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
struct ctor_tag_t {};

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() {}

    template <typename U>
    C( C<U> const& other, ctor_tag_t = ctor_tag_t{} ) { /* ... code ... */ }

    C( C const& other ) : C( other, ctor_tag_t{} ) {}

private:
    union
    {
        T t;
    };
};
```

Is there a better way? Does this tag dispatch incur any performance hit? I'd rather duplicate code if that's the case.

Comment: Why not replace `union {T t;}` with just `T t;`?

Comment: @immibis Because that would require `DefaultConstructible<T>`.

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping `t` in a union? As far as I am aware that does nothing but needlessly complicate your code.

Comment: It might help to show some sample code which uses this class in the use cases you want to support

Comment: You could use delegating constructors , if two constructors had to perform identical tasks. In fact you did exactly that in your current solution

Comment: @acwaters Like I said, `t` is inside an union so that it stays uninitialized until I want that to change; so that `t`'s default constructor is not forcibly called.

Comment: *"Does this tag dispatch incur any performance hit?"* - that's something you have to check with your own compiler and optimisation settings (e.g. g++ -S produces assembly, which is probably quicker to sanity-check than measured runtime performance, but take your pick), but I wouldn't expect it to when optimisation's enabled - the functions are implicitly inline.

Comment: Does the overload also break when using a named union instead of an anonymous one?

Comment: @Ext3h Yes. Named still causes the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my computer so can't test this at the moment, but you could probably force the resolution by using some interstitial type rather than with dummy parameters:

```
template <typename T>
struct dummy
{
    T const& t;

    dummy (T const& t): t(t) {}
    operator T const&() { return t; }
};

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    C (U const& other);

    C (C const& other): C (dummy<C>{other}) {}
};
```

No clue how well this could be inlined or what the overhead would be, and it's up for debate whether this actually represents a readability increase over your tag parameter.